# Diagonalizing using a matrix $P$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{pmatrix}$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix witth eigenvalue $\lambda$.

(a) Show that unless it is zero, the vector $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ \lambda -a \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector (I solved this)

(b) Find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal, assuming that $b \neq 0$ and that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues.

I need help with (b). Here is what I tried:

I know that if I consider the canonical basis of $ \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$, then one of the two colums of $P$ has the components of the eigenvector we considered in question (a). But how do I find the other column?

I tried looking for the eigenvalues of $A$ from scratch but I get a messy expression.

Comment: Hint 1: You can use (a) on the second eigenvalue.\\

Hint 2: You know the product of the two eigenvalues.

Comment: @xavierm02 Well (a) is the only eigenvector I have, but how do I find the second one which will constitute by second column ?

Comment: Your eigenvalues are distinct so unless one is zero, $^t(b,\lambda - a)$ and $^t(b,\mu - a)$ should work...

Comment: @xavierm02 So I can suppose the existence of another eigenvalue of A (your $\mu$) such that it's associated eigenvector will be similar to before ? And then I just do the computation and verify that I obtain a diagonal matrix right ?

Comment: @xavierm02 With regards to your second hint, we then have $\lambda \mu = \det(A)=ad-bc$ right ?

Comment: And $\lambda+\mu=tr(A)=a+d$.

Comment: I didn't suppose anything. You said "$\lambda$ is and eigenvalue $\implies ^t(b,\lambda -a)$ is an eigenvector". Since you know you have two eigenvalues, you can apply that to both.

Comment: And Dietrich is right. Use the sum instead of the product. It'll avoid problems with $0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually I didn't need these properties since the elements situated in (2,1) and (1,2) are given by: $\frac{\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc}{\lambda-\mu}$ and $\frac{\mu^2-(a+d)\mu+ad-bc}{\lambda-\mu}$ respectively.
And the numerator in both cases equals 0 since $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are both distinct eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @user1551, but for $I$, we see that $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ \lambda -a \end{pmatrix}$ is zero, so claim holds.

Comment: @user1551, but question says 'unless it is zero' and by 'it', Artin means $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ \lambda -a \end{pmatrix}$. I am surely not saying that any eigenvector of identity matrix is zero! I am saying $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ \lambda -a \end{pmatrix}$ is zero for identity  matrix.

Comment: @Silent You are right. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the two eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Note that the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the matrix.  That is:
$$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = a+d$$

Then
$$\lambda_2= a+d-\lambda_1$$

You showed that for *any* eigenvalue $r$, $\pmatrix{b\\r - a}$ is an eigenvector.  Thus, for $\mu$, $\pmatrix{b\\\mu-a}$ is an eigenvector.  Thus, our two eigenvectors are:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{v}_1 &= \pmatrix{b\\\lambda_1 - a} \\
\vec{v}_2 &= \pmatrix{b\\\lambda_2- a} = \pmatrix{b\\-\lambda_1+ d}
\end{align}$$

We know that to find the eigendecomposition of a matrix $A$, we let $P$ be the matrix with columns corresponding to the eigenvectors and $$\Lambda = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2}$$

Then, $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$.

So, for this case
$$P = \pmatrix{b & b \\ \lambda_1 - a & -\lambda_1 + d}$$